# k8s helms -> is it possible access values inside values.yaml?

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

I need to access values from the values.yaml (inside the same file):

My values.yaml file include:

```
global:
  database: "testing"

initdbScripts:
  test_echo.sh: |
    echo " {{ .Values.global.database }} "


  add_database.sql: |
    CREATE DATABASE {{ .Values.global.database }};
```

But it is not working, the global.database value is not passed into the echo or the create database in the add_database.sql.. Can someone help here ?

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to do is not possible and not intended with the helm 3 templating mechanism. Instead, you can pass the necessary value through CLI, via `--set global.database=myDbName` to your `helm install` or `helm upgrade` command like so:

```bash
helm install myReleaseName ./local/helm/directory -f ./local/helm/directory/values.yaml --set global.database=myDbName

helm upgrade myReleaseName --install ./local/helm/directory -f ./local/helm/directory/values.yaml --set global.database=myDbName
```